# Sitecore: Retrieve user input during event or..?

Tags: events, user-input, sitecore, sitecore6, pipeline

I would like to add functionality to the Sitecore Content Editor. I want to perform some action when a developer adds an item through the content tree. I understand I can create an event handler (e.g. OnItemCreating) which all works. The problem is I need user input at this point. By *at this point* I mean `OnItemCreating`, so the input needs to be there **before** the item is created.

**Are events capable of retrieving user input? If so: how? If not: any suggestions on a solution for the above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this with a [Command Template](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=16200). Chapter 4 of the Data Definition Cookbook ([PDF link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/datadefinitioncookbook-a4.pdf)) describes how you write these commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend a pipeline (for instance, `uiAddFromTemplate` or `uiDuplicateItem`) with your own processor which prompts for the user input and handles it. See `<processors>` section in web.config for more details.

Comment: Marks answer is exactly what I need. Thanks for the input anyways.

Comment: Ah, command template! Of course, that's the way to go. +1 to Mark's answer